# Can we override JSON.stringify to obtain XSS

Tags: security, web

How can we bypass this function to obtain full XSS?

```
 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        AnyFunction(response);
      }
      else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status != 200) {
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true); 
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    data = {'searchTerm':item}
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

There is only one search bar for user input.

Comment: Do you want to "override JSON.stringify", "bypass the function" or are asking whether the code is vulnerable?

Comment: Actually, this is a code of a CTF, so i know that this code is vulnerable, i also know that "console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)" will fire the XSS, and to do that we need to fullfil the "else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status != 200)" and to fullfill that, i need to parse the input such that it causes error, and the server never return 404 or 403 so, basically i'm pointing to JSON.stringify, which will cause 400.

If that make sense and if i would be able to make you understandable.